# how to identify the caller picked up the phone?

Tags: android

how to identify the caller picked up the phone? the problem is this - if the caller picked up the phone, run the program any action. for example - I'm calling the number 12345. The host number "12345" picks up the phone. I have a program written in the log "subscriber picked up the phone".

Comment: Perhaps a PhoneStateListener with onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) is what you need?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html

Comment: I need to determine that at the other end picked up the phone caller. perhaps what you advised exactly. I read and deal with it thanks. if you remember another solution please write